# como autocompletar datos con ajax y php?

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

Tengo una tabla en mysql llamada clientes con los campos (id,nombre_cliente,direcc_cliente,telef_cliente,email_cliente) y muestro los datos en la siguiente tabla atraves de una ventana modal
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora lo que quiero hacer en otra pagina es colocar un input y al escribir un nombre me salgan los registros que tengo en la base y al seleccionarlo se llenen automaticamente los campos (direccion,telefono,email) con su informacion
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero al seleccionar cualquier nombre no me aparece su informacion
me podrían ayudar por favor,les dejo mi codigo

```html
<div class="container">
   <div class="panel panel-info">
  <div class="panel-heading">
  <h4><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-edit'></i> Nueva Orden de Trabajo</h4>
  </div>
  
<div class="panel-body">
  
 <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" id="datos_factura">
  <div class="form-group row">
      
  <label for="nombre_cliente" class="col-md-1 control-label">Cliente</label>
        <div class="col-md-3">
        <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" id="nombre_cliente" placeholder="Busca y selecciona un cliente" required>
        <input id="id" type='hidden'> 
        </div>
      
       <label for="direcc" class="col-md-1 control-label">Direccion</label>
        <div class="col-md-2">
        <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" id="direcc_cliente" placeholder="Direccion" readonly>
        </div>
     
      <label for="tel" class="col-md-1 control-label">Telefono</label>
      <div class="col-md-3">
       <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" id="telef_cliente" placeholder="Telefono" readonly>
      </div>
    </div>
      
    <div class="form-group row">
       
     <label for="email" class="col-md-1 control-label">Email</label>
      <div class="col-md-3">
       <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" id="email_cliente" placeholder="Telefono" readonly>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <!--
    <div class="col-md-12">
     <div class="pull-right">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#nuevoProducto">
       <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> Nuevo producto
      </button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#nuevoCliente">
       <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Nuevo cliente
      </button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
       <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span> Agregar productos
      </button>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-print"></span> Imprimir
      </button>
     </div> 
    </div> -->
   </form> 
   
   <div id="resultados" class='col-md-12' style="margin-top:10px"></div><!-- Carga los datos ajax -->   
 </div><!--panel body-->
 </div><!--panel info--> 
    <div class="row-fluid">
   <div class="col-md-12">
   
 

   
   </div> 
   </div>
 
</div><!--container-->
 
 <script>
  $(function() {
      $("#nombre_cliente").autocomplete({
       source: "autocompletarClientes.php",
       minLength: 2,
       select: function(event, ui) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $('#id').val(ui.item.id);
        $('#nombre_cliente').val(ui.item.nombre_cliente);
        $('#direcc_cliente').val(ui.item.direcc_cliente);
        $('#telef_cliente').val(ui.item.telef_cliente);
        $('#email_cliente').val(ui.item.email_cliente);        
        
        }
      });
       
      
     });
  $("#nombre_cliente" ).on( "keydown", function( event ) {
      if (event.keyCode== $.ui.keyCode.LEFT || event.keyCode== $.ui.keyCode.RIGHT || event.keyCode== $.ui.keyCode.UP || event.keyCode== $.ui.keyCode.DOWN || event.keyCode== $.ui.keyCode.DELETE || event.keyCode== $.ui.keyCode.BACKSPACE )
      {
       $("#id" ).val("");
       $("#direcc_cliente" ).val("");
       $("#telef_cliente" ).val("");
       $("#email_cliente" ).val("");
           
      }
      if (event.keyCode==$.ui.keyCode.DELETE){
       $("#nombre_cliente" ).val("");
       $("#id" ).val("");
       $("#direcc_cliente" ).val("");
       $("#telef_cliente" ).val("");
       $("#email_cliente" ).val("");
      }
   }); 
 </script>
```

y este otro codigo

```html
<?php
if (isset($_GET['term'])){
$con=@mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', 'rootroot', 'registros');
    if(!$con){
        die("imposible conectarse: ".mysqli_error($con));
    }
    if (@mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        die("Connect failed: ".mysqli_connect_errno()." : ". mysqli_connect_error());
    }
$return_arr = array();




/* If connection to database, run sql statement. */
if ($con)
{
 
 $fetch = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM clientes where nombre_cliente like '%nombre_cliente" . mysqli_real_escape_string($con,($_GET['term'])) . "%' LIMIT 0 ,50"); 
 
 /* Retrieve and store in array the results of the query.*/
 while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($fetch)) {
  $id=$row['id'];
  $row_array['value'] = $row['nombre_cliente'];
  $row_array['id']=$id;
  $row_array['nombre_cliente']=$row['nombre_cliente'];
  $row_array['direcc_cliente']=$row['direcc_cliente'];
  $row_array['telef_cliente']=$row['telef_cliente'];
  $row_array['email_cliente']=$row['email_cliente'];
  array_push($return_arr,$row_array);
    }//cierra while
 
}//Cierra if con

/* Free connection resources. */
mysqli_close($con);

/* Toss back results as json encoded array. */
echo json_encode($return_arr);

}//cierra if isset
?>
```

cual es mi error? o como mas lo puedo hacer?
Gracias

Comment: En tu select tienes algo de: ```function(event, ui) {``` ¿nos puedes decir que es lo que trae "UI"?? (sin suponer por supuesto) :D

Answer (score 2):

Lo primero que yo haría es hacer un paso a paso de los datos que estás manejando, esto es, primero asegurarte que la consulta está trayendo los datos que son y el en formato que los necesitas para llenar el resto del formulario.

El primer detalle que noto es que en el like estás incluyendo la cadena "nombre_cliente". No conozco los datos de la tabla, pero me parecería raro que tuvieran esta cadena en su contenido, por otro lado en el limit estás poniendo `0, 50` lo que significa que estás pidiendo 0 registros a partir del número 50, lo cual nunca te traería ningún registro. Te dejo este [tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select_limit.asp) para que entiendas esa parte, entonces esa línea quedaría así:

```
$fetch = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM clientes where nombre_cliente LIKE '%" . mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_GET['term']) . "%' LIMIT 50");
```

Lo segundo que sugiero revisar es la información que llega al código donde se hace la consulta, osea, hacer un: `var_dump($_GET['term']);` Y así ir revisando qué hay en las variables tras cada llamado u operación.

La tercera observación que tengo es que estás usando el evento keyDown, este enviará la información un caracter antes de que la cadena sea completada, para que la búsqueda sea en cada letra que se escribe es mejor usar el keyUp.